# Creating a very simple linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list just to see if I can, and I am having trouble getting my head around it.  Does anyone have an example of a very simple implementation of Linked list using C#?  All the examples I have found so far are quite overdone.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

A Linked List, at its core is a bunch of Nodes linked together.

So, you need to start with a simple Node class:

```
public class Node {
    public Node next;
    public Object data;
}
```

Then your linked list will have as a member one node representing the head (start) of the list:

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
}
```

Then you need to add functionality to the list by adding methods.  They usually involve some sort of traversal along all of the nodes.

```
public void printAllNodes() {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(current.data);
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

Also, inserting new data is another common operation:

```
public void Add(Object data) {
    Node toAdd = new Node();
    toAdd.data = data;
    Node current = head;
    // traverse all nodes (see the print all nodes method for an example)
    current.next = toAdd;
}
```

This should provide a good starting point.

Comment: @Justin are you sure it is clear for a beginner what you mean by "traverse all nodes"?

Comment: @insertNick, well I used that term when I introduced the PrintAllNodes method.  But it may be slightly confusing

Comment: isnt the head always null? is it meant to be like that?

Comment: @shane, well, in this example yes.  You will have to have some special cases for adding to an empty list.

Comment: I was wondering why it would be necessary to have two classes, one for node and one for LinkedList? Why can't I declare the node inside the LinkedList class?

Comment: Answer by @jjnguy must have been fixed for printAllNodes() method. Not good to leave your answer with a bug on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @jjnguy it is not working at all.It is showing NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: The add function replaces the old node with the current one. Implemented a while loop to fix this. Now, the add function creates a hierarchical structure of nodes. `Node current = head;

            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = newNode;`

Answer (score 62):

Based on what @jjnguy said, here's the full Console App example:

```
public class Node
{
    public Node next;
    public Object data;
}

public class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;

    public void printAllNodes()
    {
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public void AddFirst(Object data)
    {
        Node toAdd = new Node();

        toAdd.data = data;
        toAdd.next = head;

        head = toAdd;
    }

    public void AddLast(Object data)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node();

            head.data = data;
            head.next = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Node toAdd = new Node();
            toAdd.data = data;

            Node current = head;
            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = toAdd;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add First:");
        LinkedList myList1 = new LinkedList();
       
        myList1.AddFirst("Hello");
        myList1.AddFirst("Magical");
        myList1.AddFirst("World");
        myList1.printAllNodes();

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Add Last:");
        LinkedList myList2 = new LinkedList();

        myList2.AddLast("Hello");
        myList2.AddLast("Magical");
        myList2.AddLast("World");
        myList2.printAllNodes();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to make 'current' as private node and inside the class and update the current node when you add a new Node under AddLast(). This would help avoid traversal of node from head to last node everytime.

Comment: Of course it would! But it would no longer be a "Simple Linked List", it will be an "Updated awesome Ronak's Mega Linked List", which wasn't part of the original question. It all comes down to the desired complexity of all of your operations. With the extra pointer, the AddLast operation will have O(1) complexity, but if you're to add DeleteLast operation, you'll need to traverse the full list again to update the new pointer to the new last node which will make it O(n). Better yet, lookup doubly linked lists... WAAAY more fun..

Comment: @Dmytro, There is an issue with your AddLast function. You have missed to assign head value after adding node. If condition should be like this:  if (head==null)
            {
                Node add = new Node();
                add.data = data;
                add.next = null;
                head = add;
            }

Comment: @Sagar, so you're creating a new variable, adding "data" and "next" to it, and then assigning this variable to head... this makes head and your new variable the same thing, right? So, if they're the same, why create a new variable just to reassign it back to head? We just perform these operations on head itself.

Comment: @Dmytro, Suddenly my brain is drain today. Why we use Node current = head; in AddLast rather than Node current = new Node()? then assign the property current.data=head.data?

Comment: @Bigeyes, We don't care for data in that particular case.. we're traversing the entire list to find the LAST node, and then add a new node to the end of it... all we care about is the 'next' for this procedure. We don't need a new node, we need a copy of 'head', which we can traverse without disturbing the original node/list

Answer (score 13):

This one is nice:

```
  namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {

    // T is the type of data stored in a particular instance of GenericList.
    public class GenericList<T>
    {
        private class Node
        {
            // Each node has a reference to the next node in the list.
            public Node Next;
            // Each node holds a value of type T.
            public T Data;
        }

        // The list is initially empty.
        private Node head = null;

        // Add a node at the beginning of the list with t as its data value.
        public void AddNode(T t)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.Next = head;
            newNode.Data = t;
            head = newNode;
        }

        // The following method returns the data value stored in the last node in
        // the list. If the list is empty, the default value for type T is
        // returned.
        public T GetFirstAdded()
        {
            // The value of temp is returned as the value of the method. 
            // The following declaration initializes temp to the appropriate 
            // default value for type T. The default value is returned if the 
            // list is empty.
            T temp = default(T);

            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                temp = current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            }
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Test with a non-empty list of integers.
    GenericList<int> gll = new GenericList<int>();
    gll.AddNode(5);
    gll.AddNode(4);
    gll.AddNode(3);
    int intVal = gll.GetFirstAdded();
    // The following line displays 5.
    System.Console.WriteLine(intVal);
}
```

I encountered it on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Nice example... but why not `GetHead()`?

Comment: I think you went a little wrong there I think the The "GetLast" was Method was correct

Comment: @A. Nosal - @Shane seems correct. You were right; the rename is not quite right. I was just thinking to add a new method for getting the list head.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one with `IEnumerable` and a Recursive Reverse method though it is no faster than the while loop in the `Reverse` method both are O(n):

```
   public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable
{
    private Node<T> _head = null;

    public Node<T> Add(T value)
    {
        var node = new Node<T> {Value = value};

        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            var current = _head;
            while (current.Next != null)
            {
                current = current.Next;
            }
            current.Next = node; //new head
        }

        return node;
    }

    public T Remove(Node<T> node)
    {
        if (_head == null)
            return node.Value;

        if (_head == node)
        {
            _head = _head.Next;
            node.Next = null;
            return node.Value;
        }

        var current = _head;
        while (current.Next != null)
        {
            if (current.Next == node)
            {
                current.Next = node.Next;
                return node.Value;
            }

            current = current.Next;
        }

        return node.Value;
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        var current = _head;

        if (current == null)
            return;

        while (current != null)
        {
            var next = current.Next;
            current.Next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }

        _head = prev;
    }

    public void ReverseRecursive()
    {
        reverseRecursive(_head, null);
    }

    private void reverseRecursive(Node<T> current, Node<T> prev)
    {
        if (current.Next == null)
        {
            _head = current;
            _head.Next = prev;
            return;
        }

        var next = current.Next;
        current.Next = prev;
        reverseRecursive(next, current);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> Enumerator()
    {
        var current = _head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Value;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerator();
    }
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am a beginner and this helped me:

```
class List
{
    private Element Root;
}
```

First you create the class List which will contain all the methods.
Then you create the Node-Class, I will call it Element

```
class Element
{
    public int Value;
    public Element Next;
}
```

Then you can start adding methods to your List class. Here is a 'add' method for example.

```
public void Add(int value)
{
    Element newElement = new Element();
    newElement.Value = value;

    Element rootCopy = Root;
    Root = newElement;
    newElement.Next = rootCopy;

    Console.WriteLine(newElement.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Node
{
    private Object data;

    public Node next {get;set;}

    public Node(Object data)
    {
    this.data = data;
     }

}

 public class Linkedlist
  {
    Node head;

    public void Add(Node n) 
    {
    n.Next = this.Head;
    this.Head = n;
    }
 }
```

using:

```
LinkedList sample = new LinkedList();
sample.add(new Node("first"));
sample.Add(new Node("second"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Could you perhaps include comments which describe what *each* line of code is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good implementation.

1. It is short, but implemented Add(x), Delete(x), Contain(x) and Print().
2. It avoid special process when add to empty list or delete the first element.
   While most of other examples did special process when delete the first element.
3. The list can contain any data type.

   ```
   using System;

   class Node<Type> : LinkedList<Type>
   {   // Why inherit from LinkedList? A: We need to use polymorphism.
       public Type value;
       public Node(Type value) { this.value = value; }
   }
   class LinkedList<Type>
   {   
       Node<Type> next;  // This member is treated as head in class LinkedList, but treated as next element in class Node.
       /// <summary> if x is in list, return previos pointer of x. (We can see any class variable as a pointer.)
       /// if not found, return the tail of the list. </summary>
       protected LinkedList<Type> Previos(Type x)
       {
           LinkedList<Type> p = this;      // point to head
           for (; p.next != null; p = p.next)
               if (p.next.value.Equals(x))
                   return p;               // find x, return the previos pointer.
           return p;                       // not found, p is the tail.
       }
       /// <summary> return value: true = success ; false = x not exist </summary>
       public bool Contain(Type x) { return Previos(x).next != null ? true : false; }
       /// <summary> return value: true = success ; false = fail to add. Because x already exist. 
       /// </summary> // why return value? If caller want to know the result, they don't need to call Contain(x) before, the action waste time.
       public bool Add(Type x)
       {
           LinkedList<Type> p = Previos(x);
           if (p.next != null)             // Find x already in list
               return false;
           p.next = new Node<Type>(x);
           return true;
       }
       /// <summary> return value: true = success ; false = x not exist </summary>
       public bool Delete(Type x)
       {
           LinkedList<Type> p = Previos(x);
           if (p.next == null)
               return false;
           //Node<Type> node = p.next;
           p.next = p.next.next;
           //node.Dispose();       // GC dispose automatically.
           return true;
       }
       public void Print()
       {
           Console.Write("List: ");
           for (Node<Type> node = next; node != null; node = node.next)
               Console.Write(node.value.ToString() + " ");
           Console.WriteLine();
       }
   }
   class Test
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           LinkedList<int> LL = new LinkedList<int>();
           if (!LL.Contain(0)) // Empty list
               Console.WriteLine("0 is not exist.");
           LL.Print();
           LL.Add(0);      // Add to empty list
           LL.Add(1); LL.Add(2); // attach to tail
           LL.Add(2);      // duplicate add, 2 is tail.
           if (LL.Contain(0))// Find existed element which is head
               Console.WriteLine("0 is exist.");
           LL.Print();
           LL.Delete(0);   // Delete head
           LL.Delete(2);   // Delete tail
           if (!LL.Delete(0)) // Delete non-exist element
               Console.WriteLine("0 is not exist.");
           LL.Print();
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
   ```

By the way, the implementation in 
http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/examples/linkedlist.htm
have some problem:

1. Delete() will fail when there is only 1 element.
   (Throw exception at line "Head.Next = Current.Next;" because Current is null.)
2. Delete(position) will fail when deleting first element,
   In other words, call Delete(0) will fail.

Answer (score 2):

I am giving an extract from the book "C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari"

Here’s a demonstration on the use of LinkedList:

```
var tune = new LinkedList<string>();
tune.AddFirst ("do"); // do
tune.AddLast ("so"); // do - so
tune.AddAfter (tune.First, "re"); // do - re- so
tune.AddAfter (tune.First.Next, "mi"); // do - re - mi- so
tune.AddBefore (tune.Last, "fa"); // do - re - mi - fa- so
tune.RemoveFirst(); // re - mi - fa - so
tune.RemoveLast(); // re - mi - fa
LinkedListNode<string> miNode = tune.Find ("mi");
tune.Remove (miNode); // re - fa
tune.AddFirst (miNode); // mi- re - fa
foreach (string s in tune) Console.WriteLine (s);
```

Comment: OP is asking about creating a custom LinkedList and you are talking about an out of the box LinkedList object available under System.Collections.Generic. Completely different topic.

Answer (score 1):

Dmytro did a good job, but here is a more concise version.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList(1);

        linkedList.Add(2);
        linkedList.Add(3);
        linkedList.Add(4);

        linkedList.AddFirst(0);

        linkedList.Print();            
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public Node(Node next, Object value)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node next;
    public Object value;
}

public class LinkedList
{
    public Node head;

    public LinkedList(Object initial)
    {
        head = new Node(null, initial);
    }

    public void AddFirst(Object value)
    {
        head = new Node(head, value);            
    }

    public void Add(Object value)
    {
        Node current = head;

        while (current.next != null)
        {
            current = current.next;
        }

        current.next = new Node(null, value);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit dodgy, why are you forcing LL to have at least 1-item? as per your constructor public LinkedList(Object initial)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DynamicLinkedList
{

    private class Node
    {
        private object element;
        private Node next;

        public object Element
        {
            get { return this.element; }
            set { this.element = value; }
        }

        public Node Next
        {
            get { return this.next; }
            set { this.next = value; }
        }

        public Node(object element, Node prevNode)
        {
            this.element = element;
            prevNode.next = this;
        }

        public Node(object element)
        {
            this.element = element;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int count;

    public DynamicLinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public void AddAtLastPosition(object element)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(element);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(element, tail);
            tail = newNode;
        }

        count++;
    }

    public object GetLastElement()
    {
        object lastElement = null;
        Node currentNode = head;

        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            lastElement = currentNode.Element;
            currentNode = currentNode.Next;
        }

        return lastElement;
    }

}
```

Testing with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DynamicLinkedList list = new DynamicLinkedList();
    list.AddAtLastPosition(1);
    list.AddAtLastPosition(2);
    list.AddAtLastPosition(3);
    list.AddAtLastPosition(4);
    list.AddAtLastPosition(5);

    object lastElement = list.GetLastElement();
    Console.WriteLine(lastElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T item;
    public Node<T> next;
    public Node()
    {
        this.next = null;
    }
}


class LinkList<T>
{
    public Node<T> head { get; set; }
    public LinkList()
    {
        this.head = null;
    }


    public void AddAtHead(T item)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
        newNode.item = item;
        if (this.head == null)
        {
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode.next = head;
            this.head = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void AddAtTail(T item)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
        newNode.item = item;
        if (this.head == null)
        {
            this.head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> temp = this.head;
            while (temp.next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteNode(T item)
    {
        if (this.head.item.Equals(item))
        {
            head = head.next;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> temp = head;
            Node<T> tempPre = head;
            bool matched = false;
            while (!(matched = temp.item.Equals(item)) && temp.next != null)
            {
                tempPre = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            if (matched)
            {
                tempPre.next = temp.next;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value not found!");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool searchNode(T item)
    {
        Node<T> temp = this.head;
        bool matched = false;
        while (!(matched = temp.item.Equals(item)) && temp.next != null)
        {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return matched;

    }
    public void DisplayList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying List!");
        Node<T> temp = this.head;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp.item);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Node class.
Then add a LinkedList class to implement the linked list
Add a test class to execute the linked list

```
namespace LinkedListProject
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public object data;
    }

    public class MyLinkedList
    {
        Node head;
        public Node AddNodes(Object data)
        {
            Node node = new Node();

            if (node.next == null)
            {
                node.data = data;
                node.next = head;
                head = node;
            }
            else
            {
                while (node.next != null)
                    node = node.next;

                node.data = data;
                node.next = null;

            }
            return node;
        }

        public void printnodes()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current.next != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(current.data);
        }
    }


    [TestClass]
    public class LinkedListExample
    {
        MyLinkedList linkedlist = new MyLinkedList();
        [TestMethod]
        public void linkedlisttest()
        {
            linkedlist.AddNodes("hello");
            linkedlist.AddNodes("world");
            linkedlist.AddNodes("now");
            linkedlist.printnodes();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple c# program to implement Single Link List with operations **AddItemStart, AddItemEnd, RemoveItemStart, RemoveItemEnd and DisplayAllItems**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace SingleLinkedList
    {
        class Program
        {
            Node head;
            Node current;
            int counter = 0;
            public Program()
            {
                head = new Node();
                current = head;
            }
            public void AddStart(object data)
            {
                Node newnode = new Node();
                newnode.next = head.next;
                newnode.data = data;
                head.next = newnode;
                counter++;
            }
            public void AddEnd(object data)
            {
                Node newnode = new Node();
                newnode.data = data;
                current.next = newnode;
                current = newnode;
                counter++;
            }
            public void RemoveStart()
            {
                if (counter > 0)
                {
                    head.next = head.next.next;
                    counter--;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No element exist in this linked list.");
                }
            }
            public void RemoveEnd()
            {
                if (counter > 0)
                {
                    Node prevNode = new Node();
                    Node cur = head;
                    while (cur.next != null)
                    {
                        prevNode = cur;
                        cur = cur.next;
                    }
                    prevNode.next = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No element exist in this linked list.");
                }
            }
            public void Display()
            {
                Console.Write("Head ->");
                Node curr = head;
                while (curr.next != null)
                {
                    curr = curr.next;
                    Console.WriteLine(curr.data.ToString());
                }
            }
            public class Node
            {
                public object data;
                public Node next;
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p.AddEnd(2);
                p.AddStart(1);
                p.AddStart(0);
                p.AddEnd(3);
                p.Display();
                p.RemoveStart();
                Console.WriteLine("Removed node from Start");
                p.Display();
                Console.WriteLine("Removed node from End");
                p.RemoveEnd();
                p.Display();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Super simple implementation. RemoveEnd() needs this: ```current = prevNode; counter--;``` in order to work properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer doesn't have an iterator; it is more basic, but perhaps not as useful.

Here is one with an iterator/enumerator. My implementation is based on Sedgewick's bag; see http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html

```
void Main()
{
    var b = new Bag<string>();
    b.Add("bike");
    b.Add("erasmus");
    b.Add("kumquat");
    b.Add("beaver");
    b.Add("racecar");
    b.Add("barnacle");

    foreach (var thing in b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thing);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Bag<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public Node<T> first;// first node in list

    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T item;
        public Node<T> next;

        public Node(T item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }


    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Node<T> oldFirst = first;
        first = new Node<T>(item);
        first.next = oldFirst;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new BagEnumerator<T>(this);
    }

    public class BagEnumerator<V> : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private Node<T> _head;
        private Bag<T> _bag;
        private Node<T> _curNode;


        public BagEnumerator(Bag<T> bag)
        {

            _bag = bag;
            _head = bag.first;
            _curNode = default(Node<T>);

        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return _curNode.item; }
        }


        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_curNode == null)
            {
                _curNode = _head;
                if (_curNode == null)
                return false;
                return true;
            }
            if (_curNode.next == null)
            return false;
            else
            {
                _curNode = _curNode.next;
                return true;
            }

        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _curNode = default(Node<T>); ;
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are already other answers here that have and iterator, and do it much better.  It takes all of 4 lines of code to write an iterator for a linked list, not all of the code you have here.

Comment: Can you show me the four lines? What do you think is much better?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help - you troll me and respond with nothing specific. I see one answer implementing IEnumerable that uses yield return. Is that better? Is that answer simpler? I'll let others be the judge.

Comment: I for one found it confusing... esp. since the OP clearly asked for simple, clear implementation. The iterator using yield IS much clearer, and simpler, and the standard way to support iteration.

Comment: Ok, sure. But it's how you implement an iterator. I think you point out why the yield keyword was introduced. To me, however, it's clearer to see it explicitly. But use a keyword if you think that's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the following LinkedList code with many features. It is available for public under the [CodeBase](https://github.com/shadinamrouti/CodeBase) github public repo.

**Classes:** 
`Node` and `LinkedList`

**Getters and Setters:** `First` and `Last`

**Functions**: 
`AddFirst(data), AddFirst(node), AddLast(data), RemoveLast(), AddAfter(node, data), RemoveBefore(node), Find(node), Remove(foundNode), Print(LinkedList)`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Codebase
{
    public class Node
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
        }

        public Node(object Data, Node Next = null)
        {
            this.Data = Data;
            this.Next = Next;
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node Head;
        public Node First
        {
            get => Head;
            set
            {
                First.Data = value.Data;
                First.Next = value.Next;
            }
        }

        public Node Last
        {
            get
            {
                Node p = Head;
                //Based partially on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list
                while (p.Next != null)
                    p = p.Next; //traverse the list until p is the last node.The last node always points to NULL.

                return p;
            }
            set
            {
                Last.Data = value.Data;
                Last.Next = value.Next;
            }
        }

        public void AddFirst(Object data, bool verbose = true)
        {
            Head = new Node(data, Head);
            if (verbose) Print();
        }

        public void AddFirst(Node node, bool verbose = true)
        {
            node.Next = Head;
            Head = node;
            if (verbose) Print();
        }

        public void AddLast(Object data, bool Verbose = true)
        {
            Last.Next = new Node(data);
            if (Verbose) Print();
        }

        public Node RemoveFirst(bool verbose = true)
        {
            Node temp = First;
            Head = First.Next;
            if (verbose) Print();
            return temp;
        }

        public Node RemoveLast(bool verbose = true)
        {
            Node p = Head;
            Node temp = Last;

            while (p.Next != temp)
                p = p.Next;

            p.Next = null;
            if (verbose) Print();

            return temp;
        }

        public void AddAfter(Node node, object data, bool verbose = true)
        {
            Node temp = new Node(data);
            temp.Next = node.Next;
            node.Next = temp;

            if (verbose) Print();
        }

        public void AddBefore(Node node, object data, bool verbose = true)
        {
            Node temp = new Node(data);

            Node p = Head;

            while (p.Next != node) //Finding the node before
            {
                p = p.Next;
            }

            temp.Next = p.Next; //same as  = node
            p.Next = temp;

            if (verbose) Print();
        }

        public Node Find(object data)
        {
            Node p = Head;

            while (p != null)
            {
                if (p.Data == data)
                    return p;

                p = p.Next;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void Remove(Node node, bool verbose = true)
        {
            Node p = Head;

            while (p.Next != node)
            {
                p = p.Next;
            }

            p.Next = node.Next;
            if (verbose) Print();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Node p = Head;
            while (p != null) //LinkedList iterator
            {
                Console.Write(p.Data + " ");
                p = p.Next; //traverse the list until p is the last node.The last node always points to NULL.
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Using @yogihosting answer when she used the Microsoft built-in LinkedList and LinkedListNode to answer the question, you can achieve the same results:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Codebase;

namespace Cmd
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tune = new LinkedList(); //Using custom code instead of the built-in LinkedList<T>
            tune.AddFirst("do"); // do
            tune.AddLast("so"); // do - so
            tune.AddAfter(tune.First, "re"); // do - re- so
            tune.AddAfter(tune.First.Next, "mi"); // do - re - mi- so
            tune.AddBefore(tune.Last, "fa"); // do - re - mi - fa- so
            tune.RemoveFirst(); // re - mi - fa - so
            tune.RemoveLast(); // re - mi - fa
            Node miNode = tune.Find("mi"); //Using custom code instead of the built in LinkedListNode
            tune.Remove(miNode); // re - fa
            tune.AddFirst(miNode); // mi- re - fa
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need both First and Head nodes?

Answer (score -1):

I have a doubly Linked List which can be used as a stack or a queue. If you look at the code and think about what it does and how it does it I bet you will understand everything about it. I am sorry but somehow I couldn't pate the full code here so I here is the link for the linkedlist(also I got the binary tree in the solution): https://github.com/szabeast/LinkedList_and_BinaryTree

Answer (score -2):

A linked list is a node-based data structure. Each node designed with two portions (Data & Node Reference).Actually, data is always stored in Data portion (Maybe primitive data types eg Int, Float .etc or we can store user-defined data type also eg. Object reference) and similarly Node Reference should also contain the reference to next node, if there is no next node then the chain will end.

This chain will continue up to any node doesn't have a reference point to the next node.

Please find the source code from my tech blog - http://www.algonuts.info/linked-list-program-in-java.html

```
package info.algonuts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class LLNode {
    int nodeValue;
    LLNode childNode;

    public LLNode(int nodeValue) {
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
        this.childNode = null;
    }
}

class LLCompute {
    private static LLNode temp;
    private static LLNode previousNode;
    private static LLNode newNode;
    private static LLNode headNode;

    public static void add(int nodeValue) {
        newNode = new LLNode(nodeValue);
        temp = headNode;
        previousNode = temp;
        if(temp != null)
        {   compute();  }
        else
        {   headNode = newNode; }   //Set headNode
    }

    private static void compute() {
        if(newNode.nodeValue < temp.nodeValue) {    //Sorting - Ascending Order
            newNode.childNode = temp;
            if(temp == headNode) 
            {   headNode = newNode; }
            else if(previousNode != null) 
            {   previousNode.childNode = newNode;   }
        }
        else
        {
            if(temp.childNode == null)
            {   temp.childNode = newNode;   }
            else
            {
                previousNode = temp;
                temp = temp.childNode;
                compute();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void display() {
        temp = headNode;
        while(temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.nodeValue+" ");
            temp = temp.childNode;
        }
    }
}

public class LinkedList {
    //Entry Point
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //First Set Input Values
        List <Integer> firstIntList = new ArrayList <Integer>(Arrays.asList(50,20,59,78,90,3,20,40,98));   
        Iterator<Integer> ptr  = firstIntList.iterator();
        while(ptr.hasNext()) 
        {   LLCompute.add(ptr.next());  }
        System.out.println("Sort with first Set Values");
        LLCompute.display();
        System.out.println("\n");

        //Second Set Input Values
        List <Integer> secondIntList = new ArrayList <Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,5,8,100,91));   
        ptr  = secondIntList.iterator();
        while(ptr.hasNext()) 
        {   LLCompute.add(ptr.next());  }
        System.out.println("Sort with first & Second Set Values");
        LLCompute.display();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```