# Can I create a position aware list item?

Tags: c#, list, graph, svg

I have a ordered list of values.

```
public class GraphItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Graphdata
{
    IList<GraphItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Of this list, I'm creating a horizontal Area graph using several SVG-polygons. One polygon for each line. So the line from one "peak" of the area needs to end halfway between the value of Item1 and Item2.

I have managed to do this by iterating over the collection and doing the calculations in the iteration. But could I be able to do this by telling the GraphItem that it's in a list, and it should check to see if it has a predecessor, and if it does, take the Value from it, and add the difference between the two values, and return it as the "polygon start" value for that line?

Note: I do not want to create one polygon for all items in the list, it needs to have it's own polygon. For now at least.

Comment: I am struggling with what the question actually is...you seem to have a good idea with the "check to see if it has a predecessor part". Essentially you are making a backwardly linked list, or doubly linked list.

Comment: Well that is the question then. I haven't used linked lists before ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a LinkedList instead of a List. In a LinkedList, each node keeps a reference to the next node, or the previous. A doubly linked list keeps track of forward and backward.

There is a built in C# implementation of this:
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

That way, you can easily find the previous or next node.

This answer: [Creating a very simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list) has a good example of the usage.

Alternatively, you can roll-your-own.
This example is as good as any other: http://seedotnet.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/doubly-linked-list/