# C# singly linked list implementation

Tags: c#, .net, list, constructor, linked-list

While trying to understand how a singly list can be implemented in C#, I came across the link below :

[Creating a very simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list).

However, as I am new to C#, I got confused by the syntax that is listed in the initial section of the discussion above.  A class named Node is being declared and there is another statement within the class declared as "public Node next".  Is this statement called a constructor?  Please help.

```
public class Node {
    public Node next;
    public Object data;
 }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a simple singly-linked list implementation the `Node` type contains a reference to the next item in the list, which is what the `next` field in the `Node` type you posted does.  This reference is used to allow iteration of the list.

The enclosing `LinkedList` class (or whatever you wish to call it) will contain a single `Node` reference to the first item in the list.  Starting from that first node you can then step through the list by getting the `next` field.  When `next` is null then you have reached the end of the list.

Take this code for example:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    public class Node
    {
        // link to next Node in list
        public Node next = null;
        // value of this Node
        public object data;
    }

    private Node root = null;

    public Node First { get { return root; } }

    public Node Last 
    {
        get
        {
            Node curr = root;
            if (curr == null)
                return null;
            while (curr.next != null)
                curr = curr.next;
            return curr;
        }
    }
}
```

The `First` property simply returns the root node, which is the first node in the list.  The `Last` property starts at the root node and steps through the list until it finds a node whose `next` property is null, indicating the end of the list.

This makes it simple to append items to the list:

```
public void Append(object value)
{
    Node n = new Node { data = value };
    if (root == null)
        root = n;
    else
        Last.next = n;
}
```

To delete a node you have to find the node that precedes it in the list, then update the `next` link from *that* node to point to the node following the one to be deleted:

```
public void Delete(Node n)
{
    if (root == node) 
    {
        root = n.next;
        n.next = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Node curr = root;
        while (curr.next != null)
        {
            if (curr.next == n)
            {
                curr.next = n.next;
                n.next = null;
                break;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few other operations you can perform, like inserting values at positions in the list, swapping nodes, etc.  Inserting after a node is fast, before is slow since you have to locate the prior node.  If you really want fast 'insert-before' you need to use a doubly-linked list where the `Node` type has both `next` and `previous` links.

---

To expand on your question in the comment...

In C# there are two basic classifications that all types fall into: value types and reference types.  The names reflect the way they are passed between blocks of code: value types are passed by value (value is copied to a new variable), while reference types are passed by reference (a reference/pointer is copied to a new variable).  The difference there is that changes to a value type parameter will have no effect on the caller's copy of the value, while changes to a reference type parameter will be reflected in the caller's copy of the reference.

The same is true of assigning values and references to variables.  In the following, the value of `a` is not changed when `b` is changed:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
b = 1;
```

That's fairly intuitive.  What might trip you up is that in C# a `struct` is also a value type:

```
public struct test
{
    public string value;
}

static void Main()
{
    test a;
    a.value = "a";
    test b = a;
    b.value = "b";

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a.value, b.value);
}
```

The above will give the output `a b` because when you assigned `a` to `b` a copy was made.  But if we change the struct for a class:

```
public class test
{
    public string value;
}

static void Main()
{
    test a = new test(); // Note the 'new' keyword to create a reference type instance
    a.value = "a";
    test b = a;
    b.value = "b";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a.value, b.value);
}
```

Because the variable `b` is a reference to the *same* object as the one variable `a` references, the output here will be `b b`.  The two variables reference the same *object*.

If you've come from C/C++ or some other similar language, you can think of reference type variables as being pointers.  It's not quite the same, and C# does actually have pointers (they're hidden from normal managed code), but it's close enough.  Until you point it to an *instance* of the type it is not fully usable.  Just like a `char*` in C/C++ isn't particularly useful until you point it somewhere.

Joseph Albahari (has written a great article about value and reference types: [*C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types*](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).  It is well worth a read, as is much of what he writes.  I would also highly recommend you consider getting one of his [**C# in a Nutshell**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/) books.

Comment: Node curr = root; Sorry, if this is a silly question, but I am just trying to become better at C# and don't want to make any assumptions. When you make this declaration, am I correct in understanding that you are instatiating an object of type Node? If so, what confuses me is how the memory space will be assigned because there is another declaration of "public Node next" inside when "Node curr" is executed?

Comment: No, the declaration is a *variable* that can hold a reference, which is conceptually similar to a pointer in C or C++.  This is true of all class variables.  To create an instance of the class object you need to use the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to create the Singly Linked List. Lets try to understand the concept. If concept is clear then you can understand the logic itself. Singly Linked List has Node with two sections. One has data value in it and other has the reference address of next node. Take the look into following code:

First We need to create the Linked List Node Class

```
/// <summary>
/// Creating the Real World Entity of Linked List Node
/// </summary>
public class LinkedListNode
{
    public Object Value { get; set; }

    public LinkedListNode Next { get; set; }

}
```

Here the class has Value and Holder to hold the reference of next Node in the sequence. Next we need to create the Linked List itself

```
/// <summary>
/// Creating the Linked List Class Itself. It defines the First and Last Nodes of Linked List
/// </summary>
public class LinkedList
{
    public LinkedListNode First { get; set; }
    public LinkedListNode Last { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to Add items into the Linked List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_value"></param>
    public void AddToLinkedList(object _value)
    {
        LinkedListNode node = new LinkedListNode();
        node.Value = _value;

        if (First == null)
        {
            First = node;
            Last = node;
        }
        else
        {
            Last.Next = node;
            Last = node;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to display all items. We can further implement the IEnumerable interface
    /// to Yield IEnumerator Interface.
    /// </summary>
    public void DisplayAllItems()
    {
        LinkedListNode current = First;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.Value);
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the Key is to Add items in to the Linked List. First we need to check if the linked list does exist or not. We check the First or Head Node in the linked List. If it is empty we assign the node as first entry point. At this stage the Last item is the first item itself.

Now this is how we add and display items

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList singlyLinkedList = new LinkedList();
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(4);
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(5);
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(7);
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(2);
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(1);
        singlyLinkedList.AddToLinkedList(10);

        singlyLinkedList.DisplayAllItems();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Let me know if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

It is class field. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Linked-List not only holds data, but a reference / pointer to the next node in the list. Since classes are reference types in C#, you don't see any special syntax that you would otherwise see in C or C++.

```
struct Node
{
    int Number;
    struct Node* next; /* this points to the next node in the linked list */
};
```

Comment: Thank you every one for your help. After reading the field descriptions on Microsoft's website, my understanding is clearer.  However, just one question: if a field declaration has the same name as the class, is there some term to define this type of field?

Comment: @user3011489 I'm sure there is... as there seems to be a term for everything... but I'm not aware of it or can't think of it off the top of my head. I think implementing solutions to problems such as linked lists, doubly linked lists, etc, are compounded when using a high level language that abstracts so much from the developer.