# How to add functionality of treatment to my own linked list

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

My question is to add treat with foreach my own linked list.
I created my linked list by seeing example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list)

And I want to add LINQ to my linked list. Where i can see it? Or how i can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement `IEnumerabe<object>` inside your `LinkedList` class:

```
public class LinkedList : IEnumerable<object>
{
        // your code
        // ....

        public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var current = this.head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.data;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
}
```

Then, `Linq` will work:

```
var result = myLinkedList.Where(data => /* some condition */)
                         .Select(data => data.ToString();
```

As far as `IEnumerable` implementation is lazy evaluted (`yield return`) you would want to throw exception when list was modified while itering (to prevent bugs or sth):

```
public class LinkedList : IEnumerable<object>
{
     long version = 0;

     public void Add(object data) //it is required for all
                                  methods that modyfies collection
     {
         // yout code
         this.vesion += 1;
     }

     public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
     {
         var current = this.head;
         var v = this.version;

         while (current != null)
         {            
              if (this.version != v) 
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("Collection was modified");

              yield return current.data;
              current = current.next;
         } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linked list needs to implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I need to rewrite all code of functionality that i need?

Comment: No, you just need to implement IEnumerable's only method GetEnumerator (see pwas' answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `AsEnumerable()` to use linq

```
public IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>()
{
    var current = root;
    while (current != null)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.NextNode;
    }
}
```