# C# Linked list nested for loops

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say I have a simple linked list in C#. For example [Creating a very simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list) any of these. And I want to iterate through that list with triple nested for loop. I can show an example with array of what I want to achieve:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
//some code to place elements into that array
for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
 for(int q = i; q<a.length; q++){
  for(int z = q; z<a.length; z++){
    //do stuff with a[i], a[q], a[z], for example send them to a function
  }
 }
}
```

How would could I do that if I had a linked list instead of an array? Let's say I need to send all these 3 elements to a function.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Implement a `GetNthElement(LinedList, int)` method that returns you the Nth element of a passed list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're going to iterate the type of linked list you're talking about with a `while` loop, e.g.

```
LinkedList a = new LinkedList();
//some code to place elements into that array
var node = a.Head;
while(node != null)
{
   var nodeQ = node;
   while (nodeQ != null)
   {
       var nodeZ = nodeQ;
       while (nodeZ != null)
       {
           // do stuff with node, nodeQ, nodeZ
          nodeZ = nodeZ.Next;
       }
       nodeQ = nodeQ.Next;
   }
   node = node.Next;
}
```