# Lists & Sub-Lists Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, nested-lists

I am trying to construct an engineering application that has lots of inputs.

*e.g.* User enter materials used for construction and have to describe their specifications but each item has different specifications and technical data so I trying to make a nested list system that has the following structure in the images below

[image]

[image]

As shown in the images I am trying to make the list dynamic so I can add and remove new lists.

I will be using C# for my interface and SQL server as my database

But I am stuck with data structure of such a list.

Comment: Well this is the typical structure of *any* relational date base. What exactly is your problem? I'm seeing tables/types `Pipe(s)`, `Sprinkler(s)`, `Material(s)`, `Schedule(s)`, etc. and fields/properties `Material`, `Size`, `Schedule`, etc.

Comment: Problem is I tried to create tables in SQL server but I was unable to create relation between tables let alone if I constructing the tables right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work for you on the C# side.

```
    public class Option
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to treat the sub options as seperate properties rather than 
        /// options for this property.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsCategory { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lists of available options for this property, or sub properties
        /// for this property if `IsCategory` is true.
        /// </summary>
        public List<Option> Options { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If `IsCategory` is false, indicates the selected option for this property.
        /// </summary>
        public Option SelectedOption { get; set; }

        public Option(string name, bool isCategory)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsCategory = isCategory;
            Options = new List<Options>();
        }
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        Option pipes = new Option("Pipes", true);
        Option material = new Option("Material", false);
        Option size= new Option("Size", false);

        Option blackSteel = new Option("Black Steel", true);
        Option stainlessSteel = new Option("Stainless Steel", true);
        Option schedule = new Option("Schedule", false);

        schedule.Options.Add(new Option("10", false));
        schedule.Options.Add(new Option("20", false));
        schedule.Options.Add(new Option("40", false));
        schedule.Options.Add(new Option("80", false));

        blackSteel.Options.Add(schedule);
        stainlessSteel.Options.Add(schedule);

        material.Options.Add(blackSteel);
        material.Options.Add(stainlessSteel);
        pipes.Options.Add(material);
        pipes.Options.Add(size);
    }
```

On the SQL side, you can define these options by giving each option a unique index, making a table like:

```
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| ID<INT> | NAME<VARCHAR>   | ISCATEGORY<BOOLEAN> | OPTIONS<VARCHAR> |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 0       | Pipes           | true                | 1,2              |
| 1       | Material        | false               | 3,4              |
| 2       | Size            | false               |                  |
| 3       | Black Steel     | true                | 5                |
| 4       | Stainless Steel | true                | 5                |
| 5       | Schedule        | false               | 6,7,8,9          |
| 6       | 10              | false               |                  |
| 7       | 20              | false               |                  |
| 8       | 30              | false               |                  |
| 9       | 40              | false               |                  |
+---------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a tree structure. Linked Lists are a great way to go about this. There is a ready LinkedList Structure in .NET, but I prefer to write my own because what you need is usually a minimal version of it.

```
class Node
{
    Dictionary<string, Node> SubLists { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

To each sublist you can either append items (if its final) or a new list of nodes, where each can again either have a list of nodes to go further down the tree or have items and be final. This is similar to how a directory in your OS works (not exactly but the idea is similar)

For further information you can do some follow up reading on linked lists, they are a basic data structure and therefore documented in a lot of online ressources.

The SQL problem can quite easily be solved by storing the document as a JSON in a nvarchar(MAX) field.

Comment: Do you have an example on mind, or know where to start ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list

In general, it should be straight forward. Just shoot up your IDE and experiment a bit, the best way to learn it is to try it!

Comment: Well, it seems I am stuck at another problem which is implementing this linked list into UI as the Form will have lists and/or combo box but as the levels increase (sub-nodes) so does the combo-box and I can't find or think of an optimum UI design to implement the linked list