# C#, Linked List, what is the difference between the last two lines?

Tags: c#, object, linked-list, nodes

need to know the difference between last two lines, I tried to run both ... first one goes good and display all, but second one doesn't please answer me as fast as you can .

thanks in advance

`enter code here`

```
 class node
 {
     public int data;
//next is a pointer
     public  node next;

     public node(int val)

     {
         data = val;   
     }

     public void print()
     {
         Console.WriteLine(data);   
     }
  }

  class list 
  {
     public node head;
     public string name;

     public list(string n)
     {
         name = n;
         head = new node(0);
     }

     public void addbegin(int newval)
     {
         node b = new node(newval);
         b.next = head.next;
  //  differnce between both
         head.next = b;
     }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] as soon as you can

Comment: sorry but I was hurry and don't have time for that ... but I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both of those lines for the code to work correctly as far as I can tell. `b.next = head.next` makes b point at whatever head was pointing at (aka the first node in the list). And then `head.next = b` makes head point at b. Therefore these two lines insert b at the front of the linked list.
[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list) with some more information on linked lists

Comment: I couldn't find the link but I got it !! thanks for your help

Comment: Forgot to add it, it's there now!