# C# how to insert a node in LinkedList on a specific index

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a school assignment and a part of this assignment is to insert a linked list node between two other nodes. This is the method.

```
public static void insert(LinkedList<Person> list, int index, Person data)
    {

    }
```

I've read some articles about LinkedList and I've found out that every linked list needs a head and a tail. I'm just not sure how to implement it, as we are only allowed to use `LinkedList<T>` and `LinkedListNode<T>` without the majority of functions they offer.

I think I have to use a while loop to get to the given index, but I don't know how to move through the LinkedList.

```
public static void insert(LinkedList<Person> list, int index, Person data)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter <= index)
        {
            if (counter == index)
            {

            }

            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
```

So I'd like to know how to insert `data` in a `LinkedList` on a specific index and how to create a head and a tail in this scenario. 
Note: I'm not allowed to change the signature of the method.

Comment: So you are not allowed to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/8adh33dd(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: No, I'm not allowed to use this method.

Comment: If you are looking for a nice introduction, watch this video (
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcNL_HLpcEs) and afterwards this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3svB0kM6f10). You will have to, as you mention, go to the specific index by navigating from the head node to your index by going to next node in the list continuously (by having a Next property) until you reach your index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a funny assignment. I wonder if your teacher knows that .Net Frameworks source code is public. Although you are prohibited to use methods like `LinkedList<T>.AddAfter` you are free to have a look at the source code and see how this method is implemented and lets say... simply copy the code? ;-)

Have a look at: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,3fc9552feecc5b5c

There you will see the implementation of this `AddAfter`-Method:

```
public void AddAfter(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    ValidateNode(node);
    ValidateNewNode(newNode);
    InternalInsertNodeBefore(node.next, newNode);
    newNode.list = this;
}
```

The part you are interested in is the internal method `InternalInsertNodeBefore()` that gets called by the `AddAfter()`-method.

Its located in the same class - you will find it by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>:

```
private void InternalInsertNodeBefore(LinkedListNode<T> node, LinkedListNode<T> newNode) {
    newNode.next = node;
    newNode.prev = node.prev;
    node.prev.next = newNode;
    node.prev = newNode;            
    version++;
    count++;
}
```

There you see how it's done and may get some "inspiration". There will be a problem with setting `count` and `version` manually. They can only be setted by functions inside your LinkedList. I think you won't be able to set the `count`-variable. But however adding a new element in this way should work.

---

**EDIT 1**: *Of course you have to get the current element of the list at the desired index first. You will get it by calling `list.ElementAt(index)`. It will return a `LinkedListNode<Person>` node. Together with your new Person-node you can call `InternalInsertNodeBefore()`. As you can see you won't need any loops.*

---

**EDIT 2**: *It seems that I have to apologize. I haven't seen that `Next` and `Previous`-Values of `LinkedListNode<T>` are read only values, too. See: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,08181ebdd4cdf907*

*Additionally Microsoft sealed the class. So it is not possible to inherit it by a new class and overide `Next` and `Previous` to add setter methods. It seems that you have to implement a completely new LinkedList- and LinkedListNode-Class by yourself. There is already a question about this topic: [Creating a very simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

This is the code I thought about. But **IT WON'T WORK** because `next`, `prev` and `head` are internal objects. They have got public references like `Next`, `Previous` and `First` but they are read only.

```
public static void insert(LinkedList<Person> list, int index, Person data)
{
    int currentIndex = 0;
    var currentNode = list.head;
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        while (currentNode != null && currentIndex <= index)
        {
            if (currentIndex == index)
            {
                data.next = currentNode;
                data.prev = currentNode.prev;
                currentNode.prev.next = data;
                currentNode.prev = data; 
            }
            currentIndex++;
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work great, the thing is, I'm not even allowed to use any complex built-in functions.

Comment: There is no complex built-in function used in my solution. Which one do you mean?

Comment: list.ElementAt(index)

Comment: Ok - I know how to handle this problem even without using `list.ElementAt(index)` and I will update my answer - BUT you shouldn't forget that this is a task for you to improve your skills. You should try to find the solution by yourself. I will update my answer in 6 hours. This should be enough time. Here are some hints: You will need a loop; Search for "iterate through LinkedList in c#"

Comment: Hey @Fihii. It seems that I have missed some awkward facts. I don't think that it is possible to manually insert a new node into a LinkedList without using the given methods of the class. I completed my answer with all details. However now you should know enough about linked lists to develop your own list- and node class to achieve your task.