# Hierarchical outlining with five numeric levels — how to insert sibling or child rows and adjust existing records?

Tags: c#, oop, document, hierarchy, outlining

I have a table with a "points" (or outlining) hierarchy:
the fields are L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 (L = level)

For example:

> 1.0.0.0.0 
>   1.1.0.0.0 
>   1.1.1.0.0 
>   1.1.2.0.0 
>   1.2.0.0.0

If I want to insert a sibling at 1.1.1.0.0 I should get a new row of 1.1.2.0.0 - and the already existing 1.1.2.0.0 should be adjusted up to 1.1.3.0.0, etc.

If I want to insert a child 1.1.1.0.0 I should get a new row of 1.1.1.1.0 with not adjustments required since there are no siblings existing at that level.

I have created procedural code for this - but it is turning into spaghetti - and I want to have an OOP solution with a class that handles these insertions and adjustments.

Can anyone please recommend even pseudo-code for handling these 2 types of insertions and required adjustments to already existing "rows"?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well each object has its own L1 to L5 fields. Simply add a chained list implementation for siblings such as: `Item1.1` has a reference to `Item1.2`, and also for a parent keep a reference to the first child. Then, when adding an element, you can traverse the structure like `while Lx not y` for each level, and when the lowest level is reached, adjust the siblings like you would any chained list.

Comment: Thanks Mat - but I am not familiar with the concept of "chained list implementation" - Can you provide a simple example in C#?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list) should get you going for a simple understanding. For a real implementation, you could simply use the `LinkedList<T>` class and call the existing method `AddAfter()`.

Comment: Thanks again, Mat - didn't even know LinkedList<T> existed! Let me dig into how this can apply to my scenario....

Comment: You really should give some code of yours though, there are too many things one can assume about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people who gave you comments I don't think really understood the issue.  You already have a table so using a LinkedList does not do anything more than a table.  You really need to pass the method a row to insert and a field to insert.  Just adding a new row with value 1.1.1.0.0 does not give enough information to renumber.

The code below I used a DataTable with each column a Field.  To make code simply I'm assuming the indexes are integers.  Code is not very complicated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Outlining outling = new Outlining();
            outling.Add(2,2);
            outling.Add(0, 2);
            outling.Add(5, 2);
        }
    }
    public class Outlining
    {
        public DataTable dt = null;

        public Outlining()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("L1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("L2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("L3", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("L4", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("L5", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 });
        }
        public void Add(int at, int level)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
            if (at < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                //move row if not last row
                dt.Rows.Remove(newRow);
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, at);
            }
            newRow.BeginEdit();
            newRow.ItemArray = dt.Rows[at + 1].ItemArray.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray();
            newRow.EndEdit();

            Renumber(at, level);
        }
        public void Renumber(int rowInsertIndex, int level)
        {
            for (int row = rowInsertIndex; row < dt.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
            {
                Boolean match = true;
                //check if columns to left still match, if no we are done
                for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i][level] != dt.Rows[i + 1][level])
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!match) break;
                dt.Rows[row + 1][level] = ((int)(dt.Rows[row + 1][level])) + 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```