# Is it correct for a C# Class to reference the same class?

Tags: c#

Learning C#, found below code snippet.

```
 class Item
    {
      public string Name;
      public Item Parent;
    }
```

What does below line means, which has the same name as a class? [see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwFKG.png)

`public Item Parent;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a very simple linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823848/creating-a-very-simple-linked-list)

Comment: "*Is this C# syntax correct?*" Why would it not be? There isn't any prohibition on having class members of the same class type. Any restriction like this would be arbitrary at best, and would severely limit the types of data and relationships that could be modeled in a particular language.

Comment: It means that the class Item contains a field of the type Item. This can be common when creating, say, a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start by the line that you understand:

```
public string Name;
//  ^    ^     ^
//  |    |     |
//  |    |     +-- Name of the field
//  |    +-------- Type of the field
//  +------------- Accessibility of the field
```

So, we have field named `Name` which is of type `string` and it is public.

Now...

```
public Item Parent;
//  ^    ^     ^
//  |    |     |
//  |    |     +-- Name of the field
//  |    +-------- Type of the field
//  +------------- Accessibility of the field
```

We have field named `Parent` which is of type `Item` and it is public.

> which has the same name as a class?

No, it does not. It has the same type as the class. Which is perfectly valid, beause a class is a *reference* type.

What it is saying is that an `Item` can have a `Parent` which would also be an `Item`.

That is, an `Item` has one or none `Parent`s, we also infer that it has none, one or multiple childs. We could take it a hierarchical structure with navigability going from the leaves to the roots (there could be multiple roots). However, there is nothing preventing loops. *And, yes, we could also take it as a linked list.*